# Python Pandas count rows based on column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, rowcount

How to get row counts based on one column in Python pandas. 
For example I have a data frame like this:

```
Name         NameTitle    Sex

John         Dr           m
Mona         Dr           f
Mary         Mrs          f
Tom          Mr           m
Jack         Mr           m 
Leila        Ms           f
Soro         Ms           f 
Christi      Ms           f
Mike         Mr           m
```

I need to count the number of name titles based on sex.
Desired output would be like this:

```
NameTitle    Sex    Count

Dr           m      1
Dr           f      1
Mrs          f      1
Mr           m      3
Ms           f      3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['NameTitle','Sex'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
  NameTitle Sex  Count
0        Dr   m      1
1        Dr   f      1
2       Mrs   f      1
3        Mr   m      3
4        Ms   f      3
```